# How can I express much greater than in Python

Tags: python, equality, comparison-operators

I need to compare two values for an if statement with the greater than equality.

```
        if delta_t > tao_threshhold:
            n = np.random.normal(0, 1)  
            rxn_vector = propensity*delta_t + (propensity*delta_t)**0.5*n 
            new_popul_num = popul_num
```

but I need the equality to be for much greater than. In maths the notation used is >> but this means something completely different in Python syntax.

Is there a way to express this much greater than equality in Python?

Cheers

Comment: The notion of "much greater" is not a fixed condition; it depends strongly on a chosen model and desired accuracy. What do you consider "much greater"? Ten times as large? 100 times as large? Why don't you just *test* "greater than 100 times the other"?

Comment: Much greater is not well defined

Comment: `>>` in math tends to be a fuzzy notion. You need to come up with an operational definition of it. Exactly how much is "much greater than"? Once you answer that question, everything is easy.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question itself is well-written and fairly interesting. `>>` is an informal notion, but it is an *important* notion nevertheless. It is a natural question to ask what it would mean in terms of programming, and not absurd to wonder if there is already a standard answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman : I am totally agree with you....that's why I upvote it...some people seems to misunderstand the meaning of the question for a mathematician. Also any mathematician whose  not comfortable with programming language could ask similar question and that is totally legitimate !

Comment: FWIW, I downvoted this question because it makes no effort to clarify what "much greater than" is intended to mean, nor what has been attempted so far. This seems especially prudent since this little effort appears to answer the question automatically.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I see what you mean, but from my point of view, the lack of clarification reflects OP's naive assumption that it had a standard meaning which didn't require clarification. Many non-mathematicians assume that everything in mathematics is precisely defined and completely rigorous (since that is the ideal it aims for). That there are ambiguities in notation, informal notions, matters of taste in basic definitions, etc., comes as a surprise to many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone is pointing out "much greater" is not a well-defined concept in mathematics/science. It is used in theoretical work to demonstrate concepts but it is open to interpretation when trying to implement the mathematical models in code.

That being said, "much greater" is often understood as "some orders of magnitudes greater" but *exaclty how many* is more or less up to you to define using intuition and experiments. It is also highly dependent on the units of measurement and the scaling of compared values (e.g. is there an upper bound `delta_t`? what values do you consider "much greater" and what values you do not? Do you have a prior knowledge or hint on how its values are distributed depending on different parameters of your algorithm?)

Practically, a way to treat it is the following:

1. Define some order of magniutde quantity:

```
E = 10e3
```

2. Implement your if statement as:

```
if delta_t > E*tao_threshold:
    ...
```

3. Be aware of precision errors: multiplying large numbers together is not safe.
4. If you are not sure how to choose approprite `E` values, you can start with the following principal:
   Intuitively, your algorithm should not depend on `E`. So, for a given set of parameters and a chosen `E` value, (if your algorithm is deterministic or proven to converge to a specific value within the chosen parameters), your algorithm should show the same results for nearby `E`'s. So you can explore different ranges of `E` for different sets of parameter values and search for stabilization regions. Assuming you have a scalar output and less than 3 parameters, this can be done by plotting the output. Just a point here: This is not the same as an optimization search. You want to find `E` values that lead to "stable" results, not "best" results.
5. **Document everything in the code, README, documentation site, and potential technical paper.** Allow the user of the code to change the selected value if needed.
6. Considering that `tao_threshold` looks like a parameter, it **may** be simpler just to explore different scales in that variable rather than introducing a "much greater" quantifier. But this greatly depends on the context of your algorithm and it may reduce that parameter's interpretability.

Answer (score 4):

I think the idea of "much greater than" largely depends on  the use case or personal preference. To answer your question; you'll need to know "how much greater than" you want it to be:

Say I want to check if delta_t is 5 times greater than tao_threshhold; i would do something like this:

```
if delta_t > 5*tao_threshhold:
```

but again the solution to this lies in a well-defined concept of "much greater than"

Comment: I think this solution is best in the sense that it allows for both 0.1 >> 0.0000001 and 1000000000 >> 10. Thinking of "much" in relative rather than absolute terms seems like a better fit for the (informal) mathematical notion.

Answer (score 0):

No, "much greater than" is a mathematical concept that has not made its way in to Python (or any other computer language, to my knowledge).

Compilers, both ancient and modern, can determine if one quantity is greater than another. This is a well-defined comparison. But "much greater than," while obvious on paper, does not yield a boolean (yes/no) answer.